# this.data.getUsers(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7

fetching details from API and trying to list the same getting error while printing the list of users was able print with same code.

following is my home.component.ts

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private data: DataService) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
        this.users = data
        console.log(this.users);
      }
    );
}
```

following is my data services code

```
getUsers() {

    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
  }
```

following is the html loop I am trying

```
<ul *ngIf="users">
  <li *ngFor="let user of users.data">
    <img [src]="user.avatar">
    <p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-Check this from your code [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-httpclient)

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  users;
  constructor(private data: DataService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data ;
    })
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="users">
  <li *ngFor="let user of users.data">
    <img [src]="user.avatar">
    <p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked... I cleared cache of npm and it worked ..